# NARX network in R

Tags: r, package, neural-network, time-series

I've tried to find a package in R to train and implement a [nonlinear autoregressive model with exogenous inputs (NARX)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_autoregressive_exogenous_model) network with no success.

I want to use it for time series forecasting as it is more powerful than an ordinary [feedforward network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network). MATLAB is not free and I did not like its [NARX toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/design-time-series-narx-feedback-neural-networks.html) as I checked online.

What functions or package are there in R for such networks?

Edit:
I have found tsDyn so far. MATLAB is not free and I did not like its NARX toolbook as I checked online. I prefer R as there are more resources out there

Comment: So, what do you think about tsDyn? You still haven't commented on it nor included any more details in your question. Please edit your question and let us know what you've learned so far.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look at this:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsDyn/vignettes/tsDyn.pdf

Comment: Nice. How did you find that? It wasn't on the first page of any of my searches.

Comment: It took me a couple of trys, but finally I just googled "nonlinear autoregressive model (NARX) in R"  and it came back as number 3

Comment: Thanks! I guess "nonlinear autoregressive exogenous model (NARX) network +R" and the rest of the variants I used was too much information.

Answer (score 1):

Type this:

```
install.packages("tsDyn");    
library(tsDyn);
nnetTs(TimeSeriesObject,m=pvalue,size=20)
```

nnetTS in R is equivalent to NARX in Matlab. Here, *pvalue* is to be used for AR(p) model. Size also can be varied, default is 20. Choose *'m=pvalue'* and *'size=j'* in such a way that your RMSE is minimised. RMSE is given by,

```
rmse= mean((residuals(nnetTs(TimeSeriesObject,m=pvalue,size=j)))^2,na.rm=T)^0.5
```